# What happens if you deploy Hangfire while a job is running?

Tags: hangfire

Let's say we have some new Hangfire job we want to deploy, and the job code is all packaged together.  It's not clear from the docs, so what happens if you deploy Hangfire while a (long-running) job is running?

Answer (score 1):

Oops.  I found it.  From the "Reliable" heading on [the Hangfire site](http://hangfire.io):

> Once a background job created and placed into a storage without exceptions, Hangfire takes the responsibility to process it at least once.
>
> You are free to throw unhandled exceptions or kill your application – background jobs will be re-tried automatically.